# Google Apps Script - Using Colon in Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm using a Google Apps Script to export form data from gmail emails. The script uses regular expressions to match on characters in the emails. Any time I discover any data that wasn't successfully exported with the script, I look for any unusual character that the script wasn't able to match on (usually diacritics). This strategy has worked well, except that I can't figure out how to match on something as simple as a colon. Any form data that includes a colon won't get downloaded by my script. Can anyone help? Simply adding a colon to the list of characters that are supposed to be matched on doesn't work. Here is the complete script. It looks at 14 different form fields.

```
function parseEmailMessages(start) {

start = start || 0;

var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

// Get the first email message of a threads
var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  subject = message.getSubject(),
  content = message.getPlainBody();

// Get the plain text body of the email message
// You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

// Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
if (content) {

  tmp = content.match(/First:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var first = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/Last:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var last = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/Title:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var title = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/Organization:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var organization = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/City:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var city = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/State:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var state = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/Country:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var country = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/Affiliation:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var affiliation = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

tmp = content.match(/Source:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var source = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

tmp = content.match(/Other:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var other = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

tmp = content.match(/Optout:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var optout = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

tmp = content.match(/Share:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var share = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

tmp = content.match(/Question:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var question = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/E-mail:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@_.\-]+)/);
  var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

  tmp = content.match(/BLANK:\s*([\s\S]+)/);
  var blank = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'BLANK';

  sheet.appendRow([first, last, title, organization, city, state, country, email, affiliation, source, other, optout, share, question]);

} // End if
} // End for loop
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the sample strings? I think that when you show the sample of "input" and "output" you need, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I've added the complete script to my original post.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. I thought when there was a sample string, it will help users think of your solution. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: By the way, I've tried escaping the colon, but that doesn't work. I'm sure there is a simple solution to matching on a colon in regular expressions. Hopefully someone can help.